# How to get rid of "Battery not charging dialog"?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery, charging, sony-xperia, mhl

I have a Sony Xperia ZR phone with Kitkat 4.4.2 and when I watch HD movies on non-MHL TV connected to the phone using a HDMI-miniUSB cable with external power source auxiliary cable, I often see a message during the movie.

> The connected power source is not sufficient. The battery is draining faster than it is charging. Please connect your phone charger.

I don't mind that the battery is discharging. I tried 1.5A power source and it is still not enough. Someone suggested the phone might be overheating, so I am now cooling it down, still didn't help. I can't get rid of the auxiliary power cable, because the MHL then won't work. My TV is not MHL enabled.

I want to get rid of that dialog at least temporarily. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I disabled similar thing in Xperia Z1 with GravityBox as I remember, it is a module for Xposed Framework, you will need to be rooted to do those things..